# Android camera FOCUS_MODE_CONTINUOUS_VIDEO and FOCUS_MODE_AUTO problems on different devices

Tags: android, camera, focus, android-camera

The question is how to configure android camera focus to achieve both on demand and auto focusing. Different devices behaves differently. *Samsung S3* and *Note2* works well with `autofocusCallback` and  **FOCUS_MODE_CONTINUOUS_VIDEO** and  **FOCUS_MODE_AUTO**.*Samsung S4* do not work with **FOCUS_MODE_AUTO**. LG G3 do not work with autofocusCallback properly  in this phone callback returns only if image had been changed during focus.*Samsung S5* do not call autofocusCallback if **FOCUS_MODE_CONTINUOUS_VIDEO** been choosed. There is a  request focus method called after preview where established.

```
public synchronized void RequestFocus()
    {
        if(false== mContext.getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA_AUTOFOCUS))
            return;
        if(mCamera!=null)
        {
            try
            {
                if(isFocusing)
                    return;
                mCamera.cancelAutoFocus();
                isFocusing=true;
                mCamera.autoFocus(mAutoFocusCallback);
                /*
                Thread focusThread = new Thread(){
                    @Override
                    public synchronized  void run() {
                        try 
                        { 
                            if(isFocusing)
                            return;
                            Thread.sleep(40);
                            if(isFocusing)
                                return;
                            isFocusing=true;



                        }
                        catch (InterruptedException e)
                        {
                            isFocusing=false;
                        }
                        catch(Exception ex)
                        {
                            isFocusing=false;
                        }

                    }};
                    focusThread.start();*/
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                Log.d("RequestFocus",ex.getMessage());
                isFocusing=false;
            }

        }

    }
```